# Duplicate and blank records are coming on joining in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

```
Here Is Distributor Records

 DistChainId    DistSupplierId  DistTranstypeId DistSupplierInvoiceNumber   DistProductDescReport   DistRawProdIdentifier   DistUPC DistProductId   DistInCatalog   DistStoreId
    130317  131220  5   CHA000377647                                        YELLOW TAIL CHARDONNAY  NULL    31259008936 32356   1   130429
    130317  131220  5   CHA000377647                                        FRANZIA 5L CHARDONNAY   NULL    83120102090 32857   1   130429
    130317  131220  5   CHA000377647                                        FRANZIA 5L WHITE ZINFANDEL  NULL    83120103196 32862   1   130429
    130317  131220  5   CHA000377647                                        FRANZIA 5L SUNSET BLUSH NULL    83120103691 32864   1   130429
    130317  131220  5   CHA000377647                                        BOTA BOX PINOT GRIGIO   NULL    82242013253 3483950 1   130429
    130317  131220  5   CHA000377647                                        BOTA BOX REDVOLUTION    NULL    82242016056 3484758 0   130429
    130317  131220  5   CHA000377647                                        RM WB PINOT GRIGIO  NULL        3716877 0   130429
    130317  131220  5   CHA000377647                                        RM WB PINOT NOIR    NULL        3716878 0   130429
    130317  131220  5   CHA000377647                                        QUAIL OAK CABERNET SAUV NULL        3711034 0   130429
    130317  131220  5   CHA000377647                                        FRANZIA 5L CHILLABLE RED    NULL        3715233 0   130429
    130317  131220  5   CHA000377647                                        QUAIL OAK MERLOT    NULL        3715777 0   130429
    130317  131220  5   CHA000377647                                        RM WB CHARDONNAY    NULL        3715960 0   130429
    130317  131220  5   CHA000377647                                        REX GOLIATH CAB NV  NULL        3716875 0   130429
    130317  131220  5   CHA000377647                                        RM WB CHARDONNAY    NULL        3716876 0   130429
    130317  131220  5   CHA000377647                                        FRANZIA 5L MOSCATO  NULL    83120003021 3491450 0   130429
    130317  131220  5   CHA000377647                                        BOTA BOX PINOT NOIR 999 82242012362 3543967 0   130429
    130317  131220  5   CHA000377647                                        BOTA BOX MINI REDVOLUTION   NULL    82242010832 3578341 0   130429
    130317  131220  5   CHA000377647                                        FRANZIA 5L DARK RED BLEND   NULL    83120003359 3600631 0   130429
    130317  131220  5   CHA000377647                                        CHILDRESS RED MUSCADINE 1.82681E+11 1.82681E+11 3711030 0   130429
    130317  131220  5   CHA000377647                                        QUAIL OAK CHARDONNAY    NULL        3711033 0   130429
```

And Here is Supplier Records

```
RecChainId  RecSupplierId   RecTranstypeId  RecSupplierInvoiceNumber    RecProductDescReport    RecRawProdIdentifier    RecUPC  RecProductId    RecTranslationValueOutside  RecTranslationCriteria2 RecTranExist    RecInCatalog    RecStoreId
130317  131220  32  377647  quail oak chard 8130800071  8130800071  3710364 3710364 8130800071  1   0   130429
130317  131220  32  377647  rex cabernet    8143403115  8143403115  3578557 3578557 8143403115  1   1   130429
130317  131220  32  377647  frnz chllble red    8312010069  8312010069  3578567 3578567 8312010069  1   1   130429
130317  131220  32  377647  chld swt rd musc    18268100042 18268100042 3710366 3710366 18268100042 1   0   130429
130317  131220  32  377647  ylw tail chrdony    3125900893  31259008936 32356   NULL    NULL    0   1   130429
130317  131220  32  377647  quail oak merlot    8130800069  81308000695 3710367 3710367 81308000695 1   0   130429
130317  131220  32  377647  quail oak cabrnt    8130800070  81308000701 3710368 3710368 81308000701 1   0   130429
130317  131220  32  377647  bota bx rdvlutn 8224201083  82242010832 3578341 NULL    NULL    0   0   130429
130317  131220  32  377647  bota bx pinot nr    8224201236  82242012362 3543967 3543967 82242012362 1   0   130429
130317  131220  32  377647  bota bx pinot gr    8224201325  82242013253 3483950 NULL    NULL    0   1   130429
130317  131220  32  377647  bota bx rdvolutn    8224201605  82242016056 3484758 NULL    NULL    0   0   130429
130317  131220  32  377647  franzia moscato 8312000302  83120003021 3491450 3491450 83120003021 1   0   130429
130317  131220  32  377647  frnzia dk rd bln    8312000335  83120003359 3600631 NULL    NULL    0   0   130429
130317  131220  32  377647  frnz chardonnay 8312010209  83120102090 32857   32857   83120102090 1   1   130429
130317  131220  32  377647  frnz whte znfndl    8312010319  83120103196 32862   NULL    NULL    0   1   130429
130317  131220  32  377647  frnz blush  8312010369  83120103691 32864   32864   83120103691 1   1   130429
130317  131220  32  377647  mondavi chrdnnay    8600300008  86003000087 33413   33413   86003000087 1   1   130429
130317  131220  32  377647  mondavi pinot gr    8600300165  86003001657 33422   33422   86003001657 1   1   130429
130317  131220  32  377647  mond wd pin noir    8600300340  86003003408 33428   33428   86003003408 1   1   130429
130317  131220  32  377647  rbrt mndvi chdny    8600387388  86003873889 33455   33455   86003873889 1   1   130429
```

When I join both table using LEFT JOIN I am getting following output

```
130317  130429  32  377647  quail oak chard 8130800071  8130800071  3710364 0   5   CHA000377647                                        BOTA BOX MINI REDVOLUTION   1.82681E+11     32356   0   0
130317  130429  32  377647  rex cabernet    8143403115  8143403115  3578557 1   5   CHA000377647                                        BOTA BOX MINI REDVOLUTION   1.82681E+11     32356   0   0
130317  130429  32  377647  frnz chllble red    8312010069  8312010069  3578567 1   5   CHA000377647                                        BOTA BOX MINI REDVOLUTION   1.82681E+11     32356   0   0
130317  130429  32  377647  chld swt rd musc    18268100042 18268100042 3710366 0   5   CHA000377647                                        BOTA BOX MINI REDVOLUTION   1.82681E+11     32356   0   0
130317  130429  32  377647  ylw tail chrdony    3125900893  31259008936 32356   1   5   CHA000377647                                        BOTA BOX MINI REDVOLUTION   1.82681E+11     32356   0   0
130317  130429  32  377647  quail oak merlot    8130800069  81308000695 3710367 0   5   CHA000377647                                        BOTA BOX MINI REDVOLUTION   1.82681E+11     32356   0   0
130317  130429  32  377647  quail oak cabrnt    8130800070  81308000701 3710368 0   5   CHA000377647                                        BOTA BOX MINI REDVOLUTION   1.82681E+11     32356   0   0
130317  130429  32  377647  bota bx rdvlutn 8224201083  82242010832 3578341 0   5   CHA000377647                                        BOTA BOX MINI REDVOLUTION   1.82681E+11     32356   0   0
130317  130429  32  377647  bota bx pinot nr    8224201236  82242012362 3543967 0   5   CHA000377647                                        BOTA BOX MINI REDVOLUTION   1.82681E+11     32356   0   0
130317  130429  32  377647  bota bx pinot gr    8224201325  82242013253 3483950 1   5   CHA000377647                                        BOTA BOX MINI REDVOLUTION   1.82681E+11     32356   0   0
130317  130429  32  377647  bota bx rdvolutn    8224201605  82242016056 3484758 0   5   CHA000377647                                        BOTA BOX MINI REDVOLUTION   1.82681E+11     32356   0   0
130317  130429  32  377647  franzia moscato 8312000302  83120003021 3491450 0   5   CHA000377647                                        BOTA BOX MINI REDVOLUTION   1.82681E+11     32356   0   0
130317  130429  32  377647  frnzia dk rd bln    8312000335  83120003359 3600631 0   5   CHA000377647                                        BOTA BOX MINI REDVOLUTION   1.82681E+11     32356   0   0
130317  130429  32  377647  frnz chardonnay 8312010209  83120102090 32857   1   5   CHA000377647                                        BOTA BOX MINI REDVOLUTION   1.82681E+11     32356   0   0
130317  130429  32  377647  frnz whte znfndl    8312010319  83120103196 32862   1   5   CHA000377647                                        BOTA BOX MINI REDVOLUTION   1.82681E+11     32356   0   0
130317  130429  32  377647  frnz blush  8312010369  83120103691 32864   1   5   CHA000377647                                        BOTA BOX MINI REDVOLUTION   1.82681E+11     32356   0   0
130317  130429  32  377647  mondavi chrdnnay    8600300008  86003000087 33413   1   5   CHA000377647                                        BOTA BOX MINI REDVOLUTION   1.82681E+11     32356   0   0
130317  130429  32  377647  mondavi pinot gr    8600300165  86003001657 33422   1   5   CHA000377647                                        BOTA BOX MINI REDVOLUTION   1.82681E+11     32356   0   0
130317  130429  32  377647  mond wd pin noir    8600300340  86003003408 33428   1   5   CHA000377647                                        BOTA BOX MINI REDVOLUTION   1.82681E+11     32356   0   0
130317  130429  32  377647  rbrt mndvi chdny    8600387388  86003873889 33455   1   5   CHA000377647                                        BOTA BOX MINI REDVOLUTION   1.82681E+11     32356   0   0
```

As you all can see **BOTA BOX MINI REDVOLUTION**  is repeating and one column whic is for DistUPC is blank. Also some of column is also blank.
Here is my join between two -

```
SELECT
 MIN(tr.RecChainId) as RecChainId,
 MIN(tr.RecStoreId) as RecStoreId,
 MIN(tr.RecTranstypeId) as RecTranstypeId,
 MIN(tr.RecSupplierInvoiceNumber) as RecSupplierInvoiceNumber,
 MIN(tr.RecProductDescReport) as RecProductDescReport,
 MIN(tr.RecRawProdIdentifier) as RecRawProdIdentifier,
 tr.RecUPC,
 MIN(tr.RecProductId)as RecProductId,
 MIN(tr.RecInCatalog) as RecInCatalog,
 MIN(td.DistTranstypeId) as DistTranstypeId,
 MIN(td.DistSupplierInvoiceNumber) as DistSupplierInvoiceNumber,
 MIN(td.DistProductDescReport) as DistProductDescReport,
 MIN(td.DistRawProdIdentifier) as DistRawProdIdentifier,
 MIN(td.DistUPC) as DistUPC,
 MIN(td.DistProductId) as DistProductId,
 MIN(td.DistInCatalog) as DistInCatalog,
 FamilyMatch=MAX(CASE when ((tr.RecProductId=td.DistProductId) AND (tr.RecProductId)=1) AND (tr.RecUPC <> td.DistUPC) then 1 else 0 end )
 --INTO #tmpCompareData 
 FROM #tmpSTRecData tr
 LEFT JOIN #tmpSTDistData td
 ON tr.RecChainId=td.DistChainId
 AND tr.RecStoreId=td.DistStoreId
 AND tr.RecSupplierId=td.DistSupplierId
 GROUP BY tr.RecUPC
```

Comment: Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve, and come back. (Your current query and result are too big.)

Comment: It would help if you explained what you are trying to do.